# How to set an environment variable for an apache2 -DFOREGROUND

Tags: php, docker, apache, shell

I have a big startup.sh script with several tasks before launching a PHP docker container. At the end of it I have the following lines:

```
set -- apache2-foreground "$@"
exec "$@"
```

The `apache2-foreground` refers to the official PHP docker file: https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/master/apache2-foreground

I have overwritten that file in the last lines doing something like:

```
[...]
    fi
done

export AA=3333

exec apache2 -DFOREGROUND "$@"
```

But when I enter my container I cannot seem to find the AA variable.

I have tried already adding `AA=3333` to the `/etc/environement` and `export AA=3333` to the `/etc/apache2/envvars` without luck.

Somehow when the `exec apache2 -DFOREGROUND "$@"` line passes, it just forgets all the `export`s and doesn't care about those directories.

The only way to make this work is to put the `AA` environment variable in the `.env` or the `docker-compose` file. But that's not what I want since the value is created in the `startup.sh`.

I would like to know how to pass an env var to the `apache2 -DFOREGROUND` command.

Comment: If by "enter the container" you mean `docker exec`, that's not a child of the entrypoint process and won't see environment variables set in the entrypoint script.  Think of it like launching another terminal window that happens to be in the same container environment; it can't see the environment variables from the main process.

Comment: (The environment variable is probably getting set correctly for the actual server process.)

Comment: Thanks David, you gave me lots of light on this subject.